# Django app links lose domain in Internet Explorer

Tags: django, apache, internet-explorer, firefox, hyperlink

I have a Django-powered page running on Apache with mod_wsgi.  It works just fine in Firefox.  When I switch to Internet Explorer, however, none of my links work.  They all drop the domain part of the link.

For example, in Firefox, if I mouse over one of my links, I see something like this:
http://mydomain.edu/pathtomystuff/linkpage/
and it works.

However, in Internet Explorer, the same link shows this when I mouse over it:
http:///pathtomystuff/linkpage/
and obviously doesn't work.

If I manually type the address in Internet Explorer, it works fine.  It's just the links.

This is probably something obvious and boneheaded.  Please forgive me :)

UPDATE
Well I did figure out something of a "solution".  I had BASE href= {{request.path}}  in my base html file (which all other pages in my site extend).  In reviewing the source code shown by IE and Firefox, both were seeing BASE href= which means request.path was not being passed to my template.  So I changed it to BASE href=mydomain.edu and it works in IE now.

This is not a great fix though because it takes away from the portability of the django app...

Comment: which version of ie are you using, I know IE7 will do some funny things with links if you have just a '/' or a '#'

Comment: was using IE7.  I have something of a solution though...

Comment: What does the source code of the <a> link look like?

Comment: looks like '<a href=/pathtomystuff/linkpage/ >'

Comment: try quotes around the href content `<a href="/pathtomystuff/page/" >`

Comment: if request is not being passed to your template, you need to have the request template context processor installed, and use RequestContext.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve portability (as well as maintainability), the easiest and most "djangonistic" way to proceed would be to use {% url  %} tags in your templates.

Note that the {% url  %} tag should be passed a view as 'argument', for example: {% url myApp.views.myView foo='bar' %} will use your urlconf to create the appropriate url that will point to the myApp view called myView, with the value 'bar' passed as the 'foo' arg.

Of course, you needn't have arguments in all your views, the foo='bar' part is purely optional (Please do note that you shouldn't specify the request argument)

The most common use would be to use a syntax such as:

```
<a href="{% url myApp.views.myView foo='bar' %}">MyLink</a>
```

Basically what you're trying to do here is reinvent the url tag, it already exists, so use it! :)

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction, but what I need to appear there is the domain, which is not in my urlconf.  I.e., root for my app is http://mydomain.edu/pathtomystuff/.  This is the "home" for my app, and the root-most location in my urlconf.  I am using the url tags successfully elsewhere in my site, but my problem is with the "base href".

Comment: Well it's pretty hackish but then you could write a context processor that uses the request's build absolute url method for your "root view" and pass it in the context.